# How to join lists element-wise in Python?

Tags: python, list

```
l1 = [4, 6, 8]
l2 = [a, b, c]
```

result = `[(4,a),(6,b),(8,c)]`

How do I do that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip).

```
l1 = [1, 2, 3]
l2 = [4, 5, 6]
>>> zip(l1, l2)
[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]
```

Note that if your lists are of different lengths, the result will be truncated to the length of the shortest input.

```
>>> print zip([1, 2, 3],[4, 5, 6, 7])
[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]
```

You can also use zip with more than two lists:

```
>>> zip([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9])
[(1, 4, 7), (2, 5, 8), (3, 6, 9)]
```

If you have a list of lists, you can call `zip` using an asterisk:

```
>>> l = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
>>> zip(*l)
[(1, 4, 7), (2, 5, 8), (3, 6, 9)]
```

Answer (score 12):

The [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip) standard function does this for you:

```
>>> l1 = [4, 6, 8]
>>> l2 = ["a", "b", "c"]
>>> zip(l1, l2)
[(4, 'a'), (6, 'b'), (8, 'c')]
```

If you're using Python 3.x, then `zip` returns a generator and you can convert it to a list using the `list()` constructor:

```
>>> list(zip(l1, l2))
[(4, 'a'), (6, 'b'), (8, 'c')]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> l1 = [4, 6, 8]; l2 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> zip(l1, l2)
[(4, 'a'), (6, 'b'), (8, 'c')]
```

Answer (score 0):

If the lists are the same length, or if you want the length of the list to be the length of the shorter list, then use zip, as other people have pointed out.

If the lists are different lengths, then you can use `map` with a transformation function of `None`:

```
>>> l1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> l2 = [9, 8, 7]
>>> map(None, l1, l2)
[(1, 9), (2, 8), (3, 7), (4, None), (5, None)]
```

Note that the 'extra' values get paired with `None`.

It's also worth noting that both `zip` and `map` can be used with any number of iterables:

```
>>> zip('abc', 'def', 'ghi')
[('a', 'd', 'g'), ('b', 'e', 'h'), ('c', 'f', 'i')]
>>> map(None, 'abc', 'def', 'gh')
[('a', 'd', 'g'), ('b', 'e', 'h'), ('c', 'f', None)]
```