# How to write a csv from a fresh new line not \n

Tags: python, csv

The result is shown to be like this.. I tried about of method no matter what it can't seem to move up. thank you in advance

1. Is there anyway for the Court array to move up??
2. Or should i delete the row directly

`if __name__ == '__main__': #start of program`

```
    master = Tk()
    newDirRH = "C:/VSMPlots"
    FileName = "J123"
    TypeName = "1234"
    Field = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
    Court = [5,4,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3]
    Field = "\n,,".join(str(x) for x in Field) # to leave a line in each Field array
    Court = "\n,,,".join(str(y1) for y1 in Court) # to leave a line in each Court array
    stringText = "Name, Type, Field, Court\n" + str(FileName) + ',' + str(TypeName) + ',' + Field + '\n,,,' + Court 

    newfile = newDirRH + "/Try.csv"
    text_file = open(newfile, "w")
    x = stringText
    text_file.write(x)
    text_file.close()
    print "Done"
```

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to join lists element-wise in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885300/how-to-join-lists-element-wise-in-python)

Comment: Your question is not very clearly worded but it seems clear that you should actually be looking for how to join two lists.

Comment: Hi i know that zip get the 2 array togehter but the problem is it can't write into csv file. I am not looking for how to join 2 lists together

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all please use the [CSV module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) to write CSV.
Secondly, use `zip` to create the list of Field / Court pairs, e.g.

```
>>> Field = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
>>> Court = [5,4,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3]
>>> zip(Field, Court)
[(1, 5), (2, 4), (3, 1), (4, 2), (5, 3), (6, 4), (7, 5), (8, 1), (9, 2), (10, 3)]
```

you can iterate over this list as follows:

```
for field, court in zip(Field, Court):
    stringText = ','.join((FileName, TypeName, field, court))
```

Comment: Hi your Code works but it is all presented in a horizontal line ... how can i make it to vertical for their respective column

Comment: It is not presented at all.  You get to do whatever you like with the `stringText` inside the `for` loop.